# Does deformation of spacetime imply deformation of space?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

In general relativity it is said that gravity is a deformation of spacetime. Does  this deformation take place only when I consider space and time as one entity, or is this a real deformation in space and in time individually?

For example, if I measure the internal angles of a gigantic triangle formed by the three stars, and there is a massive body in the center of this triangle, then, will the sum of the angles form 180° ?

Appreciate.

Comment: Similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109731/how-to-measure-the-curvature-of-the-space-time

Comment: Does deformation of a $3$-dimensional solid imply deformation of a $2$-dimensional cross-section of it? It varies on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

One can have a non-flat spacetime, with time translation symmetry and a flat $t=$constant section. An example is
$$
d\tau^2 = dt^2- \delta_{ij}(dx^i - v^i(x)dt)(dx^j-v^j(x) dt).
$$
All  components of the curvature $R_{\lambda\mu\rho\sigma}$ that do not contain a "$t$" are zero. I think that
$$
R_{tkij}= \frac 12 \partial_k(\partial_i v_j-\partial_j v_i),
$$
and that $R_{titj}$ is also non-zero, but I have not checked these recently.

Comment: What physical situation does this metric represent?

Comment: It's a version the standard ADM form of a general  metric, but with $v_i$ as the shift vector and the lapse set to unity.  It occurs as Bill Unruh's acoustic analog of the Black holes.

Comment: Interesting! Can you please link Unruh paper?

Comment: @magma Links and papers at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_metric

Answer (score -1):

As Einstein showed, space can not exist independent of time and vice versa. Riemann tensor describes the curvature of spacetime where it's written as

$$R^{\lambda}_{\beta \nu \mu} = -\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\beta \nu , \mu} + \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\beta \mu , \nu} - \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\beta \nu} \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\sigma \mu} + \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\beta \mu} \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\sigma \nu}$$

Christoffel symbols:

$$\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu \rho} = \frac{1}{2}(g_{\mu \nu , \rho} + g_{\nu \rho , \mu} - g_{\rho \mu , \nu})$$

Where all Greek letters run $(0,1,2,3) \equiv (t, x, y, z)$

So you should consider spacetime as one entity since you can't seperate them. Speaking of sum of the angles in different geometries:

Euclidean: $180$ degrees

Non-Euclidean Elliptic: $> 180$ degrees

Non-Euclidean Hyperbolic: $< 180$ degrees

Comment: "So you should consider spacetime as one entity since you can't seperate them" in a given inertial frame one does separate space and time, particularly if it is flat space,imo.  The LIGO experiment measured gravitational waves by seeing the space distortions in the arms of the interferometor, in time in our particular flat space  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4XzLDM3Py8.

Comment: I haven't yet checked the video but gravitational waves do affect time since they are perturbations in the metric, their effect is miniscule but it's there.

Comment: AFAIK in flat space,by definition one is back in a simple three space one time system.