# What is the sum of internal angles of a triangle around a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

Around Earth spacetime is curved but what about space? It's still Euclidean around Earth but what about more massive bodies.

geometrically how different is space around a massive body.

NO COORDINATES.

Comment: There is no unique way of slicing up spacetime in "slices of space". The geometry of "space" depends on this slicing. Hence this question does not have a well defined answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the sum of the angles of a triangle on Earth orbit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220055/)